# Model Bind to a List<> when Posting JavaScript Data Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to post a JavaScript data object with the following:

```
$.post(frm.attr("action"), data, function(res)
{
    // do some stuff
}, "json");
```

where 'data' takes the structure of

```
data
 - panelId
 - siteId
 - ConfiguredFactsheetId // this is an array of CheckBox ids that correspond to ConfiguredFactsheets
   - 123
   - 234
   - 345
```

With this, both site & panel are correctly instantiated & bound with their data but the List object is null.

```
public JsonResult Edit(Site site, Panel panel, List<ConfiguredFactsheet> configuredFactsheets)
{
    // do stuff
    return Json(success);
}
```

Now, I realise that my 'data' object's ConfiguredFactsheetId property is just an array of id values. Do I need to specify that each value corresponds to a configuredFactsheetId property of my ConfiguredFactsheet object? If so, my data object would take a form similart to

```
data
 - panelId
 - siteId
 - ConfiguredFactsheet // this is an array of CheckBox ids that correspond to ConfiguredFactsheets
   - ConfiguredFactsheetId:123
   - ConfiguredFactsheetId:234
   - ConfiguredFactsheetId:345
```

but this obviously won't work because every time I add a new ConfiguredFactsheetId to the object, it'll just overwrite the previous one.

I know I can do this if I built a query string of the form

```
"&ConfiguredFactsheet[i].configuredFactsheetId = " + configuredFactsheetId;
```

but I'd like to contain everything in a single data object

Any suggestions? Do I need to explain anything (probably everything!) more clearly?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: AFAIK if you have an array named `ConfiguredFactsheet`, you should have parameter names 'configuredFactsheet`. If it stores list of ints, it could be `IEnumerable<int>`. So use `public JsonResult Edit(IEnumerable<int> configuredFactsheet)`. How is panelId transformed into panel? Do you have your own ModelBinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this worked:

```
var valuesArray = objCheckBoxes.map(function()
{
    return $.getAttributes($(this));
});

var obj = new Array();
$.each(valuesArray, function(item) { obj.push($(this)[0]); });

$.each(obj, function(i)
{
    // basically I take the rule where you need to append
    // the index to the type, and I apply it here.
    data["configuredFactsheets[" + i + "].configuredFactsheetId"] = $(this).attr("configuredFactsheetId");
});
```

Note: read about [$.getAttributes](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to post:

```
?myValues=1&myValues=2&myValues=3
```

And accept it as an IEnumerable

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(IEnumerable<int> myValues) {
    ...
```