# How to bind list to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding

How to bind a list to a controller?

Code in my controller, HTTPGET and HTTPPOST :

```
 public ActionResult Client(string id)
    {               
        List<Customer> Contacts = WebService.GetContactsOfClient(id);   
        return View(Contacts);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Client(List<Customer> custs)
    {          
        // custs = null!!! Why??
        return View();

    }
```

Code in my view :

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Client", "Formulaire", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" })) { %>
        <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
            <%:item.MiseAjour %><br />
        <% } %>

        <input type="submit" />
<% } %>
```

Thank you all...

Comment: Why do you send the id in the BeginForm helper if you want the List to be sent to your view?

Comment: I edited to remove the asp.net tag, as this is not specifically asp.net related. In this context, asp.net and asp.net-mvc are completely different

Comment: @Ikaso : id is html attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding into a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058632/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-into-a-list) - been answered a bunch of times before, try searching for model binding to a list, model binding to an ienumerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get some values back in your POST action you need to POST them which is achieved using input fields:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm() { %>
    <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This outlines what you're trying to achieve.

[Model Bind to a List<> when Posting JavaScript Data Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402434/model-bind-to-a-list-when-posting-javascript-data-object/2403100#2403100)

If you have specific questions, post them

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not rendering any html input elements which are required if you want the model binder to put your model back together on the post. See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938023/asp-net-mvc-many-to-many-model-on-client-side/3939407#3939407) which shows binding to a collection and posting to back.  Also check out this post for [binding to a dynamic list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me :

```
<legend>Contacts</legend>
      <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++) { %>

            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contacts[i],"Contact") %>

        <% } %>
```

With this, I bind my list to controller!

Thank you all!!