# MVC Model View for Complex Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC and I have a Model like this

User :

FirstName : TextBox
LastName  :  TexBox
User Commitee : [CheckBox Textbox] [CheckBox Textbox] [CheckBox Textbox]

I store if user is in committee in a separate table.I need to insert selected check box value and related text box to database.How can I achieve this ? Can this be possible with using EditorTemplate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938023/asp-net-mvc-many-to-many-model-on-client-side/3939407#3939407). It is the same as what you're looking for with the check boxes being bound to a child collection.

Comment: Thanks Steve for quick reply.In my case I want to store value of Textbox next to checkbox if checkbox is selected .Textbox contains expiration date.In example above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938023/asp-net-mvc-many-to-many-model-on-client-side/3939407#3939407 it is just using checkbox right ?

Comment: You are correct. But the same technique still applies and will work for you. In the other example, there is a property bound to the checkbox. You simply need a property that you bind to the textbox as well.